# Google maps - loading markers - filter with markercluster

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I would like to ask you for help with my code. I have script where I downloading and processing json file via **$.ajax**. With filtering I also using function `moveToLocation()`. which works well but not works well with **markerclsuter** because my points after zoom are still "clustered".

```
function moveToLocation(lat, lng, zoom){
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    map.panTo(center);
    map.setZoom(zoom);
}

function addMarkers(v_data) {

        if(v_data!= null){
            removeMarkers();
        }

        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'get-places-v3.php', 
            data: {data : JSON.stringify(v_data)},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { 

                //initialize(data.regionGps[0].lat, data.regionGps[0].lng, data.regionGps[0].zoom);
                console.log(data.regionGps[0].lat + ' ' + data.regionGps[0].lng);
                moveToLocation( data.regionGps[0].lat, data.regionGps[0].lng, data.regionGps[0].zoom );

                //console.log(data.regionGps[0].lat);

                $.each(data.locations, function(index, element) {

                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(element.lat, element.lng);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map,
                        // icon: icon,
                        title: element.name
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);
                    var details = '<strong>' + element.name + '</strong><br>'  + element.adress;

                    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, details);

                });
                markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
                    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
                });
            }
        }); 
}
```

So I would like to help with 2 problems:

1) As I described above, I need to "cancel" cluster after using the filter (but if I choose Region 0 I need "reactivate" cluster)

2) I don't know why, but function "movetolocation" works just for the first time after using again didn't works.

Here is working example:
https://ugh.beladzi.cz/show-data-places-v3.php (I don't know how can I import json to codepen or jsfiddle).

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

When using markers and a markerCluster, you need to make sure both the marker array and the markerCluster object are accessible by the other functions you would like to modify them in.  Whenever you call your button click function, you need to check whether it is Region 0 or not.  If it is not Region 0 call `markerCluster.clearMarkers()` and on region 0 call `markerCluster.addMarkers(markers)`

Here is the reference doc for marker clusterer

https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html

I couldn't tell you why your panTo or setZoom functions aren't working without seeing more code.

Comment: I prepared [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Feryfery/a63bpudo/5/). Could I ask you, how do you mean? Thanks!